# Correct annotated @ToJson function for Moshi

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

Can I use JsonQualifier to annotate `Map<String, List<T1>>`? What's wrong with my function annotated with @ToJson? Runtime throws IllegalArgumentException: No @ToJson adapter for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List> annotated [@CheckMap()]

I was trying to parse something like this:

```
"A" : [
  {
    { "a": [ {T1}, {T1}, {T1} ] },
    { "b": [ {T1}, {T1} ] },
    { "c": [ {T1}, {T1} ] }
  },
  {
    { "d": [ {T1}, {T1} ] },
    { "e": [ {T1} ] },
    { "f": [ {T1}, {T1} ] }
  }
]
```

where a, b, c, d, e, f could be arbitrary name. I have to use adapter (compare to GSON, I can use alternate). T1 is a JSON map to a class.

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class CheckMap
...

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SomeElement(
    @CheckMap val s: Map<String, List<T1>>
)

...

class CheckMapAdapter {
    @FromJson
    @CheckMap
    fun fromJson(foo: Map<String, List<T1>>): Map<String, List<T1>> {
        return foo
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(@CheckMap test: Map<String, List<T1>>): String {
        return "something"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Kotlin adapter method sees the parameter type as `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.util.List<T1>>`.

You need to add `@JvmSuppressWildcards`: `@ToJson fun toJson(@CheckMap test: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards List<T1>>): String`

By the way, your adapter fromJson method looks circular, but I assume that was just a test.